# Capture video stream with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, video-capture

I made a very simple video player with a **python/pyqt videowidget**, which only has play and stop buttons. The user can also choose between reading a video file or capturing a video stream in the file menu, available devices being automatically listed (from directshow under windows).

My problem is that although my built-in webcam is perfectly well displayed on screen, such is not the case for my usb video stream encoder ([**Hauppauge WinTV-HVR-1900**](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_hvr1900.html)), for which I get only a black screen. Something is recognized though, since **the display window does adapt itself to the correct height and width**. The encoder has a built-in hardware encoder and seems to yield an **MPEG-2 stream**. The fact that VLC player displays the stream seems to indicate that codecs are not the problem.
Does anyone have an idea to get my video stream displayed?

EDIT: By the way, usb webcams I tried worked perfectly well, so my guess is my problem has something to do with the output format of the encoder not being compatible with my application.

The logic of my application:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from VideoCapture import Device
#import Gui files and classes 
import FloGui
import deviceDialog
# PyQT4 imports
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class devicedialog(QtGui.QDialog, deviceDialog.Ui_streamDialog):
    #the logic of the streaming device choice dialog
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(devicedialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.retranslateUi(self)
        self.index = None
        i=0
        self.camlist=list()
        while True:
            try:
                cam = Device(i,0)
                name = cam.getDisplayName()
                dev = [name,i]
                self.camlist.append(dev)
                i+=1
                del cam
            except:
                break
        for j in xrange(len(self.camlist)):
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.camlist[j][0])
            self.deviceListBox.addItem(item)
        self.exec_()

    def accept(self):
        selected = self.deviceListBox.currentItem().text()
        for k in xrange(len(self.camlist)):
            if self.camlist[k][0]==selected:
                self.index = k
        QtGui.QDialog.accept(self)

class Flolog(QtGui.QMainWindow,FloGui.Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    Flolog is inherited from both QtGui.QDialog and FloGui.Ui_MainWindow
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
            Initialization of the class. Call the __init__ for the super classes
        """
        super(Flolog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.retranslateUi(self)
        self.connectActions()

    def streamchoice(self):
        streamdialog = devicedialog()
        self.VideoWidget.stop()
        self.VideoWidget.path = streamdialog.index
        self.VideoWidget.load()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(True)

    def menuloadfile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
        self.VideoWidget.stop()
        self.VideoWidget.path = str(filename)
        self.VideoWidget.load()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(True)


    def playbutton(self):
        self.VideoWidget.play()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)

    def main(self):
        self.show()

    def quit_(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def connectActions(self):
        """
        Connect the user interface controls to the logic
        """
        self.actionFile.triggered.connect(self.menuloadfile)
        self.actionStream.triggered.connect(self.streamchoice)
        self.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.quit_)
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.playbutton)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.VideoWidget.stop)




if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Flologob = Flolog()
    Flologob.main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```